# reference for "compactness" coming from topology of convergence in measure

Tags: general-topology, reference-request, measure-theory, functional-analysis

I have found this sentence in a paper of F. Delbaen and W. Schachermayer with the title: A compactness principle for bounded sequences of martingales with applications. (can be found [here](http://epub.wu.ac.at/1604/))

On page 2, I quote: "If one passes to the case of non-reflexive Banach spaces there is—in general—no
analogue to theorem 1.2 pertaining to any bounded sequence $(x_n )_{n\ge 1} $ , the main
obstacle being that the unit ball fails to be weakly compact. But sometimes there
are Hausdorff topologies on the unit ball of a (non-reflexive) Banach space which
have some kind of compactness properties. A noteworthy example is the Banach
space $ L^1 (Ω, F, P) $ and the topology of convergence in measure."

So I'm looking for a good reference for topology of convergence in measure and this property of "compactness" for $ L^1 $ in probability spaces.

Thx

math

Comment: I may be misreading the paper, but it looks to me as if theorem 1.3 is precisely there to illustrate that sentence, as it is a version of 1.2 applicable to $L^1$.

Comment: In the paragraph just following theorem 1.2 they state: *Note --- and this is a "Leitmotiv" of the present paper --- that, for sequences $(x_n)_{n\geq 1}$ in a vector space, passing to convex combinations usually does not cost more than passing to a subsequence. [etc.]* In this sense theorem 1.3 says precisely that the topology in measure on the unit ball of $L^1$ is "sequentially compact", where passing to a subsequence is generalized to passing to certain convex combinations.

Comment: Another try would be the theorem stating that on uniformly integrable sets in $L^1$ the norm topology and the topology of convergence in measure coincide (and by the Dunford-Pettis theorem the former is relatively compact).

Comment: t.b. thx for your answer. I was just wondering, and obviously I misunderstood what they meant by this compactness property. Sorry for that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So that this question has an answer: t.b.'s comment suggests that the quotes passage relates to the paper's Theorem 1.3, which states:

> **Theorem.** Given a bounded sequence $(f_n)_{n \ge 1} \in L^1(\Omega, \mathcal{F}, \mathbb{P})$ then there are convex combinations
>   $$g_n \in \operatorname{conv}(f_n, f_{n+1}, \dots)$$
>   such that $(g_n)_{n \ge 1}$ converges in measure to some $g_0 \in L^1(\Omega, \mathcal{F}, \mathbb{P})$.

This is indeed "some kind of compactness property" as it guarantees convergence after passing to convex combinations.

Comment: Thanks to turn t.b.'s comment into an answer.

Answer (score 0):

If it's any help, convergence in measure is a metrizable criterion.  For the case of a finite measure space, see Exercise 2.32 in Folland, "Real Analysis", 2nd. ed., or for a general measure space see Exercise 3.22 in my lecture notes [here](http://people.math.gatech.edu/~heil/6337/spring11/section3.8.pdf).

Answer (score -2):

Under the right assumptions about the measure space, any sequence of measurable functions that is Cauchy in measure actually converges in measure to some target function. Here is a set of [lecture notes](http://people.math.gatech.edu/~heil/6337/fall07/section2.4b.pdf) by C. Heil that has more information. The full webpage for that course is [here](http://people.math.gatech.edu/~heil/6337/fall07/).

Comment: That's completeness, not compactness.